# Minified React error in react while navigation one component to anther

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error while implementing the `react-routing` here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmOgyy?editors=1010

Error

```
react.min.js:16 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at r (react.min.js:16)
    at p.a [as _instantiateReactComponent] (react.min.js:16)
    at performInitialMount (react.min.js:13)
    at p.mountComponent (react.min.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.min.js:15)
    at i (react.min.js:14)
    at r.perform (react.min.js:16)
    at s (react.min.js:14)
    at r.perform (react.min.js:16)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (react.min.js:14)
```

Could you please tell me why it is showing this error

```
var Router = ReactRouter;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var browserHistory = Router.browserHistory;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

class First extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello word</h1>;
  }
}

class Second extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Second</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={First}/>
    </Router>,document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the error occurs because of the conflict between the `development and production environment` versions of your modules. The `react-router` instance that you are using in your codepen is a `development version` and contains the full error messages. And as the React Docs say

> In the minified production build of React, we avoid sending down full error messages in order to reduce the number of bytes sent over
> the wire.
>
> We highly recommend using the development build locally when debugging
> your app since

To solve the error, use the `non-minified` version of react and react-dom

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js
```

and

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js
```

Comment: Use this cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/2.0.0/ReactRouter.js

Comment: yes it working in jsbin and codepen .but http://jsbin.com/zuvilaxosa/edit?html,js,output .. why it is not moving to next component while using `Link`

Comment: I am using `Link to` on button click why it is not showing second component

Comment: Create a separate component App as a parent of both the componetns and specify your First component as indexRoute and the second as another route. Use {this.props.children} in the parent component. Thats the way I can think of,

Answer (score 5):

After switching to non minified version of react you will see actual error:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined.

And it's happens because you are using ReactRouter v4.0 which has different API

In v4 there is no `Router` or `Routes` components.. Instead you use `BrowserRouter` and `Match` components. In your case code would look like this:

```
const {
  BrowserRouter,
  Match,
  Link
} = ReactRouter

class First extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello word!</h1>;
  }
}

class Second extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Second</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Link to='/'>First</Link>
      <Link to='/second'>Second</Link>
      <Match exactly pattern="/" component={First} />
      <Match pattern="/second" component={Second} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Documentation for react-router v4: https://react-router.now.sh/basic

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error, you can use non-minified versions of react and react-dom

Please execute the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>React Router Bug Report</title>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@0.14.2/dist/react.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@0.14.2/dist/react-dom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@2.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>

Jscode----
const {
  Router,
  Route,
IndexRoute,
  Redirect,
  Link,
browserHistory,
IndexLink
} = ReactRouter

class First extends React.Component {
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
         username: "",
      }
    // click hander
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);

  }

handleClick(e){
    //alert(this.state.username)

  }
onChangeHandler (e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
this.setState({
username :e.target.value
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
<div>
<h1>First</h1>
<input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
      {this.state.username}
<Link to="/second" ><button onClick={this.handleClick}>send data</button></Link>
</div>
    );
  }
}
class Second extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
<h1>Second</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
<Router>
<Route path="/" component={First}/>
<Route path="/second" component={Second}/>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 2):

This  error occurs because of a conflict between the development and production environment versions of your modules. The instance you are using in your code is a development version and contains the full error messages. To solve this error, you can use non-minified version of react and react-dom

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are using ReactRouter v4.0 which has different API